# Java Classes Document Naming

Tags: java

I just began learning Java.  My friend who knows much more than me has sent me a few different files which I try to run but it gives me an error.  I appologize as I don't have any of the classes on this computer and can't generate the errors right now but it appears as though the errors are due to the naming of my project as something different than a class in the file.  As soon as I try renaming things it seems to fall apart and cause more problems.  I know this is a total noob question but could someone explain the naming convention of the main class, project name, etc so I can run a project with multiple classes?
Thank you.

Comment: -1. Come back when you have an error to show us, and some concrete stuff to show. Your question boils down to "I tried compiling some file in some project but it doesn't work. What can I possibly have done wrong?". You might have done many things wrong. Read a Java tutorial to find out, or come back with a more precise question.

Comment: With so many downvotes I guess you must be right.  I just thought it was a simple enough question that I guessed most people could easily answer it but in the future I'll be more careful about having the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files with names ending in `.java` (the ones that contain your actual code) are called source files. Each source file is allowed to contain one `public` class. If a source file does contain a `public` class, then its filename has to match the class name.

For example, if your class contains

```
public class HelloWorld {
```

then the filename has to be `HelloWorld.java`.

Each source file is also allowed to contain any number of non-`public` classes. Those classes do not have anything to do with the filename.

Also, you mentioned the name of your project. There is no such thing as a project in Java. Projects are a concept used by programs that help you write Java code (these are called IDEs), like Eclipse and NetBeans. Are you using one of those programs?

Comment: Yeah I'm using Netbeans.  I created a project and then tried to put in the source code from my friend and was surprised when it didn't compile.  It was clear there was an issue with the class name and then it just spiraled down from there.  Thanks for the info and now I know how I can build the project without errors.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your class name and the file name has to be the same if:

- your class is declared as public, then the file name should also be the same,
- your class name can be different than the file name if you dont find the public keyword in front of it.

Good luck and keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the rules:

One public class per .java file
Class name must match the .java file name
Directory structure for .java files must match package structure (e.g. package com.foo w/ class Bar must live in com/foo/Bar.java)

Answer (score 0):

1) Classes by convention are camel-cased starting with a capitol letter. (ex. ThisIsMyClass.java)

2) The "main" method may be in any class you desire as long as the method has the correct syntax,  Java has no preference where the main method is.  Though you will see oftentimes in tutorials the main method is placed in a class named the same as the project (ex. MyProject.java)

3) As long as your imports and packages are correct, you can have a project with multiple classes without following any naming conventions. (This is not advised, Java developers love their conventions.)